# Paypal / Google checkout integration

Tags: php, paypal, google-checkout

Is it possible to integrate the Google Checkout API or Paypal API with my marketplace? I am using PHP to generate the market, one auction at the time. I have a MySQL database containing all of the market actions, however, I was wondering. Can I use either Google Checkout or Paypal to dynamically generate the **Checkout** process, and give the proceeded money to the user whose posted action, then notify me?

I am able to load User details from the MySQL database aswell.

- I looked at the 'StackExchange' network, however; I could not figure out where to place this question. Therefore I assumed this was the best place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Checkout as the term implies is pretty much what it says - it allows a merchant to outsource their checkout operations to Google. I don't think it's a fit because in your case, "merchant" is "dynamic" - its different sellers across auctions. Additionally, Google Checkout isn't for person-to-person payments - its specifically for a merchant (store) to sell products and service at it's web site and have the checkout process handled by Google.

Look into [Paypal Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-payments).

You can also look into [Amazon FPS](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/business?sn=devfps/o) .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with your project's terms such as 'generate the market', 'market actions'

PayPal has [reference tranactions](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECReferenceTxns) in which you can charge same customer's credit card again without storing actual credit card.

Authorize.Net has [CustomerPaymentProfile](http://www.authorize.net/support/CIM_SOAP_guide.pdf) in which they store your customers's credit cards. Then you can submit each customer's paymanet profile, and they'll charge the card for you.

I'm not familiar with Google's automatic checkout without actual credit card.